# MySQLDump without 'DATA DIRECTORY'

Tags: mysql, bash

I'm using MySQLDump via system calls to export tables from one database and import them (selectively) on another. My issue is that on the source database server, some tables are in a different (encrypted) directory, and on the target server, there is no target Data Directory.

My current command looks something like this:

```
mysqldump --skip-opt --skip-comments --no-create-db --disable-keys
  --extended-insert --quick --create-options --login-path=sourcedb
  source_database_name source_table |
mysql --login-path=targetdb target_database_name
```

On those tables stored on the encrypted disk, the dump looks something like this:

```
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `AnExampleTable` (
  `id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type_id` int unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'FK The system type.',
  `resource` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT,
  `created_at` timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ActionSystemPendingId`),
  UNIQUE KEY `resource_type` (`type_id`,`resource`),
  KEY `created_at` (`created_at`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 DATA DIRECTORY='/mnt/mysqlEncrpyted/';
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `AnExampleTable` DISABLE KEYS */;
-- data inserts
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `AnExampleTable` ENABLE KEYS */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;
```

Essentially all I want to do is drop `DATA DIRECTORY='/mnt/mysqlEncrpyted/'` from the query without having  to resort to `sed`.

This is done (as I said) via system calls, and some tables are fine because they don't live on a special data directory. All I want is a flag that strips it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such option.  `mysqldump` uses the output the server generates from `SHOW CREATE TABLE` to generate its output.  It doesn't build the output from scratch.

Use `sed`.  Or pipe through Perl, or a similar tool.

Comment: In the end, I just piped it through sed. Not a pretty solution, but it worked.

Comment: I wrote (and continue to work on) a utility, currently internal but that I plan to eventually release, tenatively called `my-dump-filter`, that understands the mysqldump output format and can rewrite dump files as a stream -- doing things like rewriting database names, include/exclude entire schemas from a list of names, changing storage engines, splitting out the table definitions and data into separate files, removing `DEFINER` statements (for Amazon RDS).  I'll add removing or changing the data directory to the wish list.